# Convert byte array to bitmap

Tags: android, c++, bitmap

Currently, I'm working in an Android application project at my University, that post image to a web-service and using OpenCV to process this image in some way. In android, I convert a bitmap to byte array like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

Then, how can I convert that byteData into bitmap again in C++ in web-service in order to use it in image processing?
I'm not so good in C++, please help.

Comment: Your example is not C++.  The syntax `byte[]` is invalid.  You may be programming in C# or Java.  The correct syntax is `byte byteData[]`.

Comment: You are not sending a bitmap but a jpg. So you have to convert a jpg to a bitmap at server side. But why would you? If i were you i would not send a jpeg compressed bitmap to begin with. Do you start with a bitmap?  Where do you get the image from? If it is a jpg from file then just send the file and do not use bitmapfactory, bitmap and so.